# JDBC QueryTimeout only working for some vendors

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to add query timeouts to my system using JDBC. I am using the statement.setQueryTimeout function to do this. I know that this value is being set on statements I create using connection.createStatement, prepareStatement etc., as I have checked it using statement.getQueryTimeout. However, when testing with different databases (mysql, mssql, oracle and db2) and only mysql functions properly and all the others don't actually timeout

Any idea what could cause this? I am not sure why things would work at a high level for one setup but not the others, as I am using the standard provided drivers

Comment: Issue with that VedorId Query is crashig with that VendorId and it's return timeout error becuase it's  not getting any result within that time duration

Comment: Check version of Oracle JDBC drivers you used. For Oracle it is possible at least on protocol level. While using OCI you can use OCIBreak from any thread regardless of what the main thread is doing with the connection. The OCIBreak will send OOB(out-of-band) packet to server to cancel query execution. Usally you have wait for some time till OCI feature is also impemeted in JDBC. In this case the problem was that OOB TCP feature was not supported by JVM itself.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll definitely look into that; OCIBreak might be a good enough work around

Comment: @Madden OCIBreak is function from OCI(C) client. PS: There is also method "Cancel()" in JDBC drivers. This method should to the same as OCIBreak and also be thread-safe. But AFAIK you should use driver named ojdbc7.jar (not ojdbc6.jar). See docs http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/apxtblsh.htm#JJDBC28983

Comment: Of-topic: I've just checked docs for Statement.cancel() implementation in Oracle JDBC driver version 10g and 11g. The 10g version has an additional sentence in it " `In some circumstances, the server is hung, but JDBC does not receive an IOException. Statement.cancel() does not free the thread that initiated the Statement.execute(). Due to limitations in the Java thread API, there is no acceptable workaround.` ". In 11g this sentence was removed. So did they found the workaround? Or did they just bough Java, and therefore the removed this complaint?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are those drivers haven't implemented it (yet?). Some database servers don't have a way to define a query timeout. Some database servers might support query cancellation, but that requires that the driver itself tracks this and sends a cancellation to the server asynchronously, which may or may not be handled in a timely fashion on the server (eg because the database server can't handle that cancellation until the query is finished as the connection thread is currently working on the query).

Theoretically the client could 'abandon' the query, but that usually means the connection itself becomes unusable because the server side of the connections is still working (or the returned response from the server is not processed).

Long story short: it is a hard problem, and not all database have adequate support to allow for this JDBC feature.

Comment: Definitely, I mean the databases I am using all say they support JDBC::setQueryTimeout as standard. I think the threading issue you mention would be worth investigating though; previous research I've done has shown that the MySQL implementation creates a timeout thread which has its own connection and handles closing the query itself, whereas other vendors create a thread which just sends a message back to the parent, and then the parent has to handle it

Comment: @Madden Cancelling requests from a different connection is an interesting approach. It does add some complexity as for a lot of database server the "statement identity" is connection-local and not server-global, not to mention the overhead of needing two connections per connection, or the coordination for a shared 'cancellation'-connection. That said I know that for example Oracle has a hard time cancelling statements, even if you use the admin features available to perform said cancellation ;)